# gsutil cp hangs on obtain initial access_token

Tags: access-token, gcloud, gsutil

When using gsutil to copy a file it hangs indefinitely:

```
gsutil cp gs://gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/index.csv.gz .
```

Running gsutil with with debugging `gsutil -D cp` outputs:

```
gsutil version: 4.28n
boto version: 2.48.0
python version: 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
OS: Linux 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
multiprocessing available: True
using cloud sdk: True
pass cloud sdk credentials to gsutil: True
config path(s): /home/gardnera/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/my@email/.boto
gsutil path: /u/devon0/gardnera/yes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil
compiled crcmod: True
installed via package manager: False
editable install: False
Command being run: /u/devon0/gardnera/yes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil -o GSUtil:default_project_id=landsatdata1 -D cp gs://gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/index.csv.gz /home/gardnera/
config_file_list: ['/home/gardnera/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/my@email.com/.boto']
config: [('debug', '0'), ('working_dir', '/mnt/pyami'), ('https_validate_certificates', 'true'), ('debug', '0'), ('working_dir', '/mnt/pyami'), ('default_project_id', 'landsatdata1')]
INFO 0110 17:16:21.952356 base_api.py] Calling method storage.objects.get with StorageObjectsGetRequest: <StorageObjectsGetRequest
 bucket: u'gcp-public-data-sentinel-2'
 object: u'index.csv.gz'
 projection: ProjectionValueValuesEnum(noAcl, 1)>
INFO 0110 17:16:21.953642 base_api.py] Making http GET to https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/o/index.csv.gz?fields=contentType%2Cname%2Cgeneration%2CcustomerEncryption%2Cmd5Hash%2CcontentEncoding%2Ccrc32c%2Cetag%2CmediaLink%2Csize&alt=json&projection=noAcl
INFO 0110 17:16:21.954131 base_api.py] Headers: {'accept': 'application/json',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
 'content-length': '0',
 'user-agent': 'apitools gsutil/4.28 Python/2.7.13 (linux2) google-cloud-sdk/184.0.0 analytics/disabled'}
INFO 0110 17:16:21.954305 base_api.py] Body: (none)
INFO 0110 17:16:21.954441 client.py] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
```

but hangs indefinitely on `obtain initial access_token`

I've been digging into this issue for awhile now and can't seem to find any answer. Testing on other machines I am unable to replicate the issue. A reinstall of gcloud did not fix the issue.

Anyone have any thoughts as to what might be going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK looks like the problem was with the .config files. I deleted the `~/.config/gcloud` folder and the issue has resolved itself