# Google Cloud ML: repeating "Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token", then "Job failed"

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-ml, gsutil

I am trying to run a training job on Google Cloud ML Engine. I am submitting the job using

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_`date +%s` \
--job-dir=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train \
--packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz,/tmp/pycocotools/pycocotools-2.0.tar.gz \
--module-name object_detection.model_tpu_main \
--runtime-version 1.13 \
--scale-tier BASIC_TPU \
--region us-central1 \
-- \
--model_dir=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train \
--tpu_zone us-central1 \
--pipeline_config_path=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/data/pipeline.config
```

However, after the job is created and all the required packages are installed, I start to repeatedly get these messages:

[image]

until the job fails with this output:

[image]

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609164/google-cloud-ml-engine-job-failed-due-to-an-internal-error-cant-execute-a-j), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609471/internal-error-on-google-cloud-ml) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198686/gsutil-cp-hangs-on-obtain-initial-access-token) without any success.

I suppose the problem is related to authentification, so I followed this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started), but that didn't help.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Can you send your job-id to cloudml-feedback@google.com

Comment: @YashSonthalia sure! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there are some issues with TPU allocation. I solved the problem by changing the TPU to GPU, so the command for job submitting is changed to

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_`date +%s` \
--job-dir=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train \
--packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz,/tmp/pycocotools/pycocotools-2.0.tar.gz \
--module-name object_detection.model_main \
--runtime-version 1.13 \
--scale-tier BASIC_GPU \
--region us-central1 \
-- \
--model_dir=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train \
--pipeline_config_path=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/data/pipeline.config
```

**UPDATE**

I have contacted @Yash Sonthalia as he asked me to do. Very shortly the problem got fixed. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a solution. Why would someone want to change from TPU to GPU? There is a reason people paying money for TPU right?